# object is not subscriptable, what?

Tags: python, types, typeerror

I'm trying to loop a snippet of code to the length of a list, I found that just using `len(menu)` would throw out an error so I re-wrote it and got this:

```
length = 0
for i in menu:
    length = length + 1
for i in range [length]:
    text_file.write(menu[i])
```

this is throwing out the error:

```
"TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"
```

I've looked around and can't find any help online with the issue. could you guys help out?

Comment: What is `range [length]` supposed to be? Did you mean `range(length)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the square brackets to a rounded ones:
`for i in range (length):`

Moreover, you can perform the same more effectively with:

```
for i in range (len(menu))
```

Comment: Or even simpler would be `for i in menu: text_file.write(i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in menu:
    text_file.write(i)
```

credit to UnholySheep for the answer, it worked great!